# When using sympy, why is a permutation group not a group?

Tags: python-3.x, sympy, symbolic-math

I've run this code, pretty plainly expecting the result to be `True` and yet it's not.  I'm not able to make heads or tails of the documentation regarding this behavior, so if someone could explain it to me I'd appreciate it.

```
from sympy.combinatorics.named_groups import SymmetricGroup

G = SymmetricGroup(3)
print(G.is_group())
```

[Edit: Weirdly, I tested this and it came out `True`:

```
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation
from sympy.combinatorics.perm_groups import PermutationGroup
from sympy.combinatorics.named_groups import SymmetricGroup

G = SymmetricGroup(3)
H = PermutationGroup( Permutation(0,1,2) )
print(G.is_normal(H))
```

]

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer, it's that the "group", when created, only stores a generating set.  To see this run the following code which only prints two elements.

```
from sympy.combinatorics.named_groups import SymmetricGroup

G = SymmetricGroup(3)
for i in G:
    print(i)
```

However, I'm now left with the curious fact that this code prints `True False` for reasons I haven't been able to discover:

```
from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation
from sympy.combinatorics.perm_groups import PermutationGroup
from sympy.combinatorics.named_groups import SymmetricGroup

G = PermutationGroup(list(SymmetricGroup(3).generate()))

H = PermutationGroup( Permutation([0,1,2]) ) # This should just be the trivial
                                            # subgroup and therefore normal

print(H.is_subgroup(G), H.is_normal(G))
```